# What are differences between INSERT and UPDATE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

It seems `INSERT` and `UPDATE` do the same things to me.

Is there any occasions where I should use `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE` and vice versa?

Comment: If you really believe that: 1) Create a table, 2) immediately run an UPDATE statement 3) SELECT * from the table.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), the `INSERT` is the 'C' and the `UPDATE`is the 'U'. They are two of the four basic functions of persistent storage. The other two are `SELECT` and `DELETE`. Without at least these four operations, a typical database system cannot be considered complete.

Use `INSERT` to insert a new record.

Use `UPDATE` to update an existing record.

Comment: Why couldn't you just insert over an existing record. Maybe SQL doesn't allow it, but are they not then equivalent to the same thing?

Comment: in CQL, (not MySQL) you can insert data onto exitings data. But Primary keys must be same.

Answer (score 49):

You cannot UPDATE a row that's not in a table.

You cannot INSERT a row that's already in a table.

Comment: What if you need to add data into a column that may or may not have data? Is there  a forced insert mode, or some sort of INSERT-UPDATE hybrid?

Comment: In mysql, we have EXISTS keyword and IFNULL keyword to check wheter the referenced data is in a certain state. it would look like INSERT INTO table_name IFNULL follower by UPDATE table_name IF EXISTS. This approach may take more lines then desirable and honestly there may be a better solution, but at least it will work

Answer (score 4):

Insert is for adding data to the table, update is for updating data that is already in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Insert is for putting in a fresh record to the table. while the update enables you to modify the inserted record e.g. modifying data type etc.

Answer (score 1):

An `UPDATE` statement can use a `WHERE` clause but `INSERT` cannot.

Comment: This is not true.  There are examples of INSERT using WHERE at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score -1):

Insert can be useful to insert new record in BLANK row.
While Update can be used to update row which is NOT BLANK.