# SQL insert into fails using substring from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create process using `substring` from `table1.column2` and insert results into `table1.column6`. I am trying the query below but my insert fails. It tries to insert into another column (*column1*) which is the id column. I specify *column6* but it does not work.

```
Insert into table1(column6)
   Select substring(column1,1,3)
   from table1
```

Error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Column1ID', table 'dbo.table1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Please check the definition of table1 column6 and check if it allows NULL value.

Comment: The error is very clear. Have you researched it before submitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your table contain data , but column6 is empty (null), you must use update command

```
update table1 set column6 = substring(column1,1,3)
```

that use data stored into table1 and update column6

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between the `insert` and `update` statements - insert creates a brand new row, whereas update updates a row that already exists (even if data in a particular column for a row does not yet exist)

[What are differences between INSERT and UPDATE in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002500/what-are-differences-between-insert-and-update-in-mysql) - i realize you're sql server but same principle applies.

It sounds like you may actually be trying to update a column value, not insert a new row with a value in a column.

Given the following table and data:

```
table1
----
Id int primary key identity(1,1)
column1 varchar(50) not null
column6 varchar(50) null

id    column1    column6
-----
1     some value    null
2     some other value    null
```

note that if you were to attempt your query:

```
insert into table1(column6) select substring(column1,1,3) from table1
```

this would attempt to take "some value" and "some other value" into new rows 3 and 4, with null in column1, and the substring values into column6.  Note that this would fail because you're attempting to insert rows into table1 with null values (column1) in a not nullable column.

what you (probably) actually want is something like:

```
update table1
set column6 = substring(column1,1,3)
```

which will *update* the table for (in this case all rows) setting column6s value to the substring values of column1

Comment: I see what the error I made is now. I tried the update and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to update the table. Use ISNULL to avoid null values.

```
 UPDATE table1 SET column6 = ISNULL(SUBSTRING(column1,1,3), '')
```

If you insist on insert. Do check all the columns accept null other than Column6. And Query will insert a bulk of data.

```
Insert into table1(column6)
Select ISNULL(SUBSTRING(column1,1,3), '')
from table1
```