# Updating existing Access file syntax error

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a problem with updating an existing Access table. I have an Access database that's supposed to sort some .log files with two columns: `filename` and `filedate`. I have the filename and filedate in an Excel file that I have made from sorting through 100+ .log files, so there are 100+ files that should be linked to Access

[image: Access][image]

I get an error every time and have tried many different things. The problem is that I don't know how to write the syntax. Can someone help me with that please? I want `A -> filename` and `B -> filedate` so that every pair gets its own ID

```
import pypyodbc


UDC = r'C:\Users\Kaiser\Documents\Access\UDC.accdb'
# DSN Connection
#constr = " DSN=MS Access Database; DBQ={0};".format(UDC)
# DRIVER connection
constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/USERS/DOCUMENTS/ACCESS;DBQ=C:/USERS/DOCUMENTS/ACCESS/UDC.accdb"

# Connect to database UDC and open cursor
db = pypyodbc.connect(constr)
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE * INTO [tblLogfile]" + \
      "FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:/Users/Documents/Access/Excel.xls].[Tab$];"

cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

**error**

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.')
```

Comment: First decide what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002500/what-are-differences-between-insert-and-update-in-mysql -- Then read up on the appropriate syntax.

Comment: @andre I have read about the UPDATE statement but I don´t understand how I should write it in my sgl variable, there is no examples on how to link up the excel file with access and that's what im trying to do.

Comment: But then I don't know if doing it my way is the best way to do this transfer, so if you have some suggestions ill be glad to hear

Comment: *Insert is for adding data to the table, update is for updating data that is already in the table.* -- You need an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL something like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO [tblLogfile] (<list of field names>) SELECT <list of matching field names> FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:/Users/Documents/Access/Excel.xls].[Tab$];"
```