# insert into select on duplicate mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, insert, centos, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to update on duplicate record in MySQL,

I have a table with many column but i want to update only some column from another table with same desc as current table but it is not updating records.

my query is:

> insert into backup_prochart.symbol_list(ticker,end_date,cur_date)
>   select ticker,t.end_date,t.cur_date from prochart.symbol_list t where
>   ticker=t.ticker and ticker= 'MAY17' on duplicate key update
>   end_date=t.end_date,cur_date=t.cur_date;

another query i tried

> insert into backup_prochart.symbol_list(ticker,end_date,cur_date) select t.ticker,t.end_date,t.cur_date from prochart.symbol_list t where ticker=t.ticker and t.ticker= 'MAY17' on duplicate key update end_date=t.end_date,cur_date=t.cur_date;

can anyone tell me whats wrong with my query.?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your, problem query 1 works fine for me. Can you publish your table definitions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
INSERT INTO backup_prochart.symbol_list (ticker, end_date, cur_date) 
SELECT ticker, end_date, cur_date FROM prochart.symbol_list WHERE ticker = 'MAY17' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_date = values(end_date), cur_date = values(cur_date);
```

Of course the column "ticker" must be defined as unique for the table "backup_prochart.symbol_list".

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are trying to update a record, but you are using an `INSERT` statement. Shouldn't you be using `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`?

Difference between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002500/what-are-differences-between-insert-and-update-in-mysql)

Note that you can use `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in a single query.

Comment: sir there are lots of rows to be either insert or update depends on realtime situation i can not use update for all of them. so it might not helpful specially in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try this. its worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO employee_projects
            (employee_id,
             proj_ref_code)
SELECT ep.employee_id,
       ep.proj_ref_code
FROM   hs_hr_emp_projects_history ep
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   employee_projects p
                   WHERE  ep.employee_id = p.employee_id
                          AND ep.proj_ref_code = p.proj_ref_code)
```