# On duplicate key gives Invalid token

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to update `name_code` from `employee_migration` by numbers from `cdclient` from table `clientref`.

```
 INSERT INTO employee_migration (name_code)
      Select cl.cdclient 
        From clientref cl 
  Inner Join employee_migration em  
          ON cl.client like upper(em.name)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name_code VALUES (cl.cdclient)
```

I get this error:
Invalid token.

```
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 1.
ON.
```

Comment: `select` inside is working. I get numbers but I have to update them in the table

Comment: why do you add `VALUES (cl.cdclient)` at the last line?

Comment: @lucumt, I found an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366136/insert-into-select-on-duplicate-mysql-query

Comment: Maybe it's because the 'ON DUPLICATE' comes right after the inner join, can you try putting a "WHERE 1=1' for ex between the join and the on duplicate?

Comment: The error isn't a MySQL error it looks like you are trying a execute a MySQL syntax query on a other DBMS

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am working in IBExpert

Comment: I think it's a little conflict between inner join and on duplicate

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Comment: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use **Firebird** server (which was not said, but which looks like by your error text) then you have `MERGE` command for it.

However, if you use **Interbase** server, then I do not know how you can write that statement there, consult Interbase manuals then: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2017/en/Statement_and_Function_Reference_(Language_Reference_Guide)

You can check the server you work with in **IBExpert** using *Services -> Server Properties and Log* menu.

Assuming you use Firebird version 2.1 or newer

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html

For example something like this:

```
MERGE INTO employee_migration dest
USING (
      Select cl.cdclient, em.ID
        From clientref cl 
  Inner Join employee_migration em  
          ON cl.client like upper(em.name)
      ) as src
ON dest.ID = src.ID -- or whatever your key columns are

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.namecode = src.cdclient

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (namecode, ID, ....)
    VALUES ( src.cdclient, ...., ...........)
```

However without sample data your request seems of little practical sense.

Your `join` condition is `cl.client like upper(em.name)` - which is "many to many": for every row in `clientref` there can be many corresponding rows in `employee_migration` and vice versa.

So you would probably be matching and updating rows in `employee_migration as dest` with MANY candidate rows from the `src` query.

- By SQL standard it should generate an immediate error.
- By Firebird 2.x implementation - it would instead do those updates one after another, overwriting previous updates, and only the last candidate row would have their result persisted.

Comment: Can I use the code you wrote? if yes, I have this error: Column unknown.
SRC.CLIENT.

Comment: You have to understand the **example** I drafted and complete it, because I obviously do not know your tables and their columns. More so, I have doubts that your request has a practical sense, cause it seems to updates every row **randomly** picking one of many candidates... That being said, my code does not have `SRC.CLIENT` in it.

Comment: If I create two small tables: table 1 (name, code1) and table 2 (name,code2). How to copy code1 from table1 to code2 in table 2. In general, I mean this

Comment: then you probably have "name" as `PRIMARY KEY` in both table. Well, first of all you have to decide what are you planning to do with values in table1 with the name that are missed from table2? Ignore them, insert them, copy them to table3, whatever. That has to be decided. Then, if you want to match the tables on `table1.name = table2.name` then that is what you have to do. Where did you got that `ON cl.client like upper(em.name)` from? why not `cl.client = em.name` ? Do you understand what `UPPER` and `LIKE` do there? They introduce "many to many" instead of "one to one"

Comment: For the utterly simplified example `table_source( ID, value )` and  `table_destination( ID, value )` and strict matching rule `ID = ID` you can write `MERGE` by the documentation or wiki or by any googled example. It is just that your question looks very different from that "two small tables" example.

Comment: Ok, I understood you. I did a query which works (no errors), but it doesn't update anything. I think as you said the problem is in "many to many". My working day is over and tomorrow I'll try to use Generators to autoincrement ids to do iterations in my table. Hope, it will be done. I'll write about my result tomorrow and make your answer best))

Comment: Hopefully you did not forget to COMMIT transaction after the query? Also, IBExpert on FB shows how many rows were updated after the query. There may be different cases: no rows updated, or many rows updated with the same data, that they already had

Comment: Alternatively, use [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-update-or-insert.html) (although that isn't usable for this specific case).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ivo Gelov exactly suggested it (check his initial answer edition). It can be made working, if to put it for the goal... Just the main problem is we are not sure what the topic starter wants and I wonder if she knows it surely herself... No tables, not input data, no output data, not even FB version....

Comment: Glad to hear! Both done the job and hopefully learned something new :-D

Answer (score 1):

Firebird has a different syntax than MySQL

```
MERGE INTO employee_migration
  USING (Select cl.cdclient 
    From clientref cl 
    Inner Join employee_migration em ON cl.client like upper(em.name)) AS tmp
  ON employee_migration.name_code = tmp.cdclient
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET name_code = tmp.cdclient
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name_code) VALUES(tmp.cdclient)
```

### UPDATE

As @arioch-the properly pointed out you need the [MERGE command](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-merge.html). My original solution was actually wrong.

Comment: Hm, probably it works with VALUES() and refuses with SELECT ... Then you need a trigger to silently convert the failing INSERTs into UPDATEs.

Comment: `THEN INSERT (name_code)` - would not do, you would have to have ALL columns for the SQL INSERT statements ( except for auto-generated or auto-computed ones )

Comment: Another trick would be to use `EXECUTE BLOCK` for making "anonymous temporary procedure", there you run `FOR SELECT` loop and execute that very `UPDATE OR INSERT` for every row in the loop. Though usually still better to write correct merge. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html & https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-forselect

Comment: Completely agree with you. I have not worked with Firebird for a while (I am using Postgres) so I always wonder how some very simple things are made in such a complex and inconvenient manner ...