# Insert into with several select inside

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to insert into a table values which I take from another table. I am using IBExpert. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO employeemove (cdemployeemove,cdclient,datestart,cdclientwhere,cdcateg)
  SELECT gen_id(EMPLOYEEMOVE_NEXTCODE, 1),
  SELECT em.name_code from employee_migration em where em.cdclient = 1,
  SELECT em.fired_date from employee_migration em where em.cdclient = 1,
  cdclientwhere, -- from employeemove
  cdcateg -- from employeemove
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Firebird?

Comment: firebird, but as I know there are differences but sometimes it's the same

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you really solved that many-to-many problem mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476351/ - then use `MERGE` command. If you did not, then there would hardly be any other way, than for you to present some significant part of input and desired output data and for us in a long Q&A session to ask you WHY you were picking one rows and not others, until we can figure out your intention. Only after this understanding would get reached "in human words" would it become possible to translate it to SQL. There's just no way to do "Something like" - everything is more or less like anything

Comment: Please do not tag with mysql if you are using Firebird, and please include DDL of the tables involved, sample data and expected result of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you want `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO employeemove (cdemployeemove, cdclient, datestart, cdclientwhere, cdcateg)
    SELECT gen_id(EMPLOYEEMOVE_NEXTCODE, 1), em.name_code, em.fired_date,
           cdlientwhere, cdcateg
    FROM employee_migration em 
    WHERE em.cdclient = 1;
```

Edit:

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO employeemove (cdemployeemove, cdclient, datestart, cdclientwhere, cdcateg)
    SELECT gen_id(EMPLOYEEMOVE_NEXTCODE, 1), em.name_code, em.fired_date,
           emo.cdlientwhere, emo.cdcateg
    FROM employee_migration em LEFT JOIN
         employeemove emo
         ON emo.cdclient = em.cdclient
    WHERE em.cdclient = 1;
```

Comment: unknown cdclientwhere and cdcateg. They are from employeemove. I've got an error

Comment: I need to copy values cdclientwhere and cdcateg from the table I insert in