# INSERT INTO with the CASE function

Tags: postgresql, case, sql-insert

so I have this table I'm working with and I created an additional column (column B) to distinct some values. Column A are integers and I am trying to use the CASE function to identify their respective names and then insert them into Column B. I thought I had the code right but when I query it claims to be successful but returns just null values in Column B. Where am I going wrong?

This is my current code:

```
INSERT INTO astro(star_name)
SELECT 
CASE star_type
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Brown'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Red_Dwarf'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'White_Dwarf'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Main_Sequence'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Supergiant'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Hellagiant'
    ELSE 'Basic'
END
FROM astro
```

I expected for the star_name to return the corresponding names, but instead I just got a whole bunch of wack ahh nulls :/
I appreciate your help community, thanks!

Comment: I think you should read this: [What are differences between INSERT and UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002500/what-are-differences-between-insert-and-update-in-mysql)  that question i about MySQL, but it also  applies to PostgreSQL

Comment: It seems like this info should be a generated column or even just provided by a view, to avoid normal form violations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-update.html) to change existing rows, not [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-insert.html)

More examples here:

- [PostgreSQL UPDATE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update/)
- [PostgreSQL INSERT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-insert/)

```
UPDATE astro
SET star_name = CASE star_type
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Brown'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Red_Dwarf'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'White_Dwarf'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Main_Sequence'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Supergiant'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Hellagiant'
    ELSE 'Basic'
END
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/xFR1Ax_e)

Comment: Sheesh! That's all it took huh, thanks! @Luuk